# NoMethodError in Users#show undefined method `following' for User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on a project similar to a twitter clone. I've looked around for others with the same error and haven't been able to find another example of this problem. However, I am running into an error that is the following:

```
undefined method `following' for #<User:0x000055ae42d0d158
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/users/show.html.erb

```
app/views/shared/_stats.html.erb:5:in 

`_app_views_shared__stats_html_erb__231770652215433765_47103466733040'
    app/views/users/show.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___1734427599225406369_47103466794880'
Here is user model:
```

Extracted source (around line #5):

```
<% @user ||= current_user %>
<div class="stats">
  <a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>">
    <strong id="following" class="stat">
      <%= @user.following.count %>
    </strong>
    following
  </a>
  <a href="<%= followers_user_path(@user) %>">
    <strong id="followers" class="stat">
      <%= @user.followers.count %>
    </strong>
    followers
  </a>
</div>
```

And place where second error is on 11 row:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section>
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
    <section class="stats">
      <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= render 'follow_form' if logged_in? %>
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.where(activated: true).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)    # Not the final implementation!
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
      # Handle a successful update.
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  # Confirms an admin user.
  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end

  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.following.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
  end

    # Confirms the correct user.
  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end

end
```

Here is my User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def self.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def self.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  # Activates an account.
  def activate
    update_attribute(:activated, true)
    update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end

  # Sets the password reset attributes.
  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest, User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

 # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

 # Returns true if a password reset has expired.
  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end

  # Defines a proto-feed.
  # See "Following users" for the full implementation.
  def feed
    Micropost.where("user_id = ?", id)
  end

  private

  # Converts email to all lower-case.
  def downcase_email
    self.email = email.downcase
  end

  # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
  def create_activation_digest
    self.activation_token  = User.new_token
    self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
  end

end
```

And here is Relationship model:

```
class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

And this is my db schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_02_07_112022) do

  create_table "microposts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "picture"
    t.index ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_microposts_on_user_id_and_created_at"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_microposts_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "relationships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "follower_id"
    t.integer "followed_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_followed_id"
    t.index ["follower_id", "followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id_and_followed_id", unique: true
    t.index ["follower_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "remember_digest"
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.string "activation_digest"
    t.boolean "activated", default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

following method is not there in user.rb

has_many :following

Comment: It doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= @user.following.count %>
```

Your `User` model don't have `following` association or scope or method in it. That's why it is giving error.
For `@user.following` to work you should have `following` method in user model or scope or association.

For eg:

```
def following 
  #your logic for following code 
end
```

Comment: It throws error 'undefined local variable or method `params' for #<User:0x0000559bde23a0f8>' on 3-rd line of 'following' method of my updated user.rb model file :(

Comment: you can't get "params" on user model.

Comment: you have to create follower/following model and table.

Comment: From where you got above code. Please check other models as well. You will find \

Comment: I have edited my post and added Relationship model and db schema

Answer (score 0):

Your method is wrong. It's located inside your model just before the 'private' section. What is it you want to do with that method? You can't put that inside your model. Looks like you copied the controller action inside your model again.

```
def following
  @title = "Following"
  @user  = User.find(params[:id])
  @users = @user.following.paginate(page: params[:page])
  render 'show_follow'
end
```

Comment: I added this method as recomendation of comment below

Comment: You can add a method called following inside you model, but what you did now is not working. How do you define your followers? You can't expect that your app knows what a follower is just by adding a method with a name. Do you have a follower model? Or some tables with follower IDs?

Comment: I have edited my post and added Relationship model and db schema